# Printing the value of a specific key in dict

Tags: python

How do I access a variable's value?

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.food = "Soup"

    def get_food(self):
        return self.food

food_dict = {
    "Soup": 3,
}

x = Example.get_food

for x in food_dict.keys():
    print food_dict[x]
```

The above command to the operator to print results in a syntax error. I have tried to return the value instead, but this results in a KeyError:0 message. How do I print the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing a key with an iterator.

This `x` is a reference to a specific key, which you can then use to get a specific value in the dict like so:

```
x = Example.get_food()
print food_dict[x] # Value at key x
```

This `x` iterates through the dict by key, you can then use it to print the corresponding values:

```
for x in food_dict.keys():
    print food_dict[x] # will print each value of the dict
```

As a side note, you don't even need to specify `.keys()`, Python will figure that out for you:

```
for x in food_dict:
    print food_dict[x]
```

Comment: Actually, this raises a syntax error.

Comment: What is the error? Have you actually stored a value in the dict yet by doing something like `food_dict["Soup"] = "Clam chowder"`?

Comment: The above code stores the value 3 for the "Soup" key. I get a syntax error with the caret pointing at the "t" in food_dict, just before the "[x]".

Comment: Whoops didn't even see that. But what I got upon testing was an unbound method error, which is fixed by replacing `x = Example.get_food()` with `x = Example().get_food()` (another thing I didn't originally catch). Otherwise, the code should run fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
    print food_dict[x]   # what ...?
```

Comment: this raises an exception for a syntax error!